# 'insert into' from more source-tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I would like to insert into one table from three different tables,
but the first one statement below  works, next one does not.
What should I do?

```
SELECT * into NewTable from ta where farm like'%aa';
SELECT * into NewTable from tb where farm like'%aa';
SELECT * into NewTable from tc where farm like'%aa';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
select * into NewTable  from (
SELECT * from ta where farm like'%aa'
Union all
SELECT * from tb where farm like'%aa'
Union all
SELECT * from tc where farm like'%aa'
)a;
```

Comment: Next time, I wan't
select * into NewTable  from 
    SELECT * from td where farm like'%aa'
show error: the NewTable is already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Query `select * into NewTable` in fact **creates** that `NewTable` according to results of select query and then insert these results.

So in order to insert into existed table after first query, change second and third ones to

```
insert into NewTable 
select * from tb ...

insert into NewTable 
select * from tc ...
```

Notice - all tables in this case should has the same structure.

Comment: Sorry, I wanna put data in one NewTable.

Comment: What do you mean? Again, first query creates table, and fills it with data. Second and third adds their data to the same `NewTable` created by first query.

Comment: insert into NewTable 
select * from tb ...  is OK.

insert into NewTable 
select * from tc ...  it doesn't because NewTable is already existed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of three inserts better do one and UNION your results:

```
SELECT * into NewTable 
from ta 
where farm like'%aa'

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
from tb
where farm like'%aa'

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
from tc 
where farm like'%aa';
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, I wan't 
select * into NewTable from 
SELECT * from td where farm like'%aa' 
show error: the NewTable is already exist.